# Vuforia auto focus in android Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am using Vuforia with Unity3d. Camera run fine on various devices but give blur/focus problem on phones like HTC , Nexus 6p. I am using Autofocus script on ARCamera.

Below is the code:-

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using Vuforia;
 public class CameraFocus : MonoBehaviour {

 bool FocusModeSet;

void Awake()
{
    //CameraDevice.Instance.SetFocusMode (CameraDevice.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO);
    FocusModeSet  = CameraDevice.Instance.SetFocusMode (  
        CameraDevice.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO); 

    if (FocusModeSet == false) 
    {  
        Debug.Log ("to set focus mode Failed (mode unsupported) ().");  
    } 
}
}
```

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I created script, which is setting Camera Focus Mode in a specific Vuforia states. You can take a look on my sample code below:

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

void Start() {
    VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.RegisterVuforiaStartedCallback(OnVuforiaStarted);
    VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.RegisterOnPauseCallback(OnVuforiaStarted);
}

private void OnVuforiaStarted() {
    CameraDevice.Instance.SetFocusMode(
    CameraDevice.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO);
}
```

I pin this script to the standard `ARCamera` object.

Comment: I have already tried it, but yet it's not working on many devices like Nexus 6p.

Comment: I found that they have some problems with Nexus in [Release Notes](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Release_Notes/Vuforia-SDK-Release-Notes). There is also a thread about Nexus 5 problems [there](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/device-support/nexus-5x-arcamera-issue-unity). You can always report an issue with your device [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/device-support/how-report-device-issue).

Comment: Where did you put this script file? And how to call it?

Comment: How to pin this script to the ARCamera?